# How can i see my current active users in my Firebase Analytics dashboard

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I connected my android app to new Firebase Analytics api and now see information on analytics dashboard about daily , weakly, monthly active users count.

But i can't see active current users (count) in my dashboard as was in previous Google Analytics tool.

How can i show my current active users in my Firebase Analytics dashboard?

Answer (score -2):

-Add firebase Analysic to you app
[image: Desc]

-After a few hour you can find your app users analysic in your firebase console on "Analytics Tab".
[image: Desc]

Comment: I said that have already added api to my app and see information on dashboard. But I don't see currently active users which I need